# c# -Cannot implicitly convert int to int[]

Tags: c#

I know that the specific question was asked many times.
Tried, checked and read but not possible to make out.

1. How could I possible request an input that would be the total elements of an array that would store any given value?
2. How to convert int to int[]?

Please check the my code below

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{

  Console.WriteLine("Could you please provide " +
      "the total numbers of elements of this array?");

  int input = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

  int[] A = new int[] { };

  for (int i = 1; i<=input; i++)
  {
       A[i] =(1 / i * i);
       Console.WriteLine(A[i]);           
  }

}
```

Thanks

Comment: Could you please elaborate on what you are trying to achieve? It is not clear to me what your actual question is.

Comment: You can't convert int to int[]. One is a number, the other is a collection of numbers. Beyond that, I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: `A[i] =(1 / i * i);` makes no sense here.. it will be converted to int. You will get an array that will look like `[1,0,0,0,0,0,....]`

Comment: The code in the question is not attempting to convert an int to an int[], but has other problems. Can you clarify *exactly* what the problem is?

Comment: Be aware that if this is for an exercise, so be it, but for real code, arrays are almost always the worst collection to pick by default. Also, your loop code doesn't make a great deal of sense `(1/i*i)` when `i` is an `int` ranging from 1-something will be `1` for i equal to 1 and`0` for all others, because that's what you get doing integer maths

Comment: @ Damien_The_Unbeliever  -exactly this is an exercise ,where I needed to be able to create an array of (input by user number of elements  1,2,3...123 etc)it does not matter ,then using a loop be able to save each outcome as well !Logic did not make sense(A[i]=(1/i*i))apologies,but even if it was I would still get an error exception.Is there any way to overcome  that-Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
 int input = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

 // This will create an input with the amount of spaces inserted by the user
 int[] A = new int[input];

  for (int i = 1; i <= input; i++)
  {
       A[i - 1] = (1 / i * i);
       Console.WriteLine(A[i - 1]);    
  }
```

You can't convert an `int` to `int[]`, but you can insert an `int` into a space of the array, as I have done in the `for` example. Hope it helps

Comment: `(1 / i * i)` will return value with decimal and might be not int which was expected

Comment: @AnkushMadankar This will not result in an exception, it will be converted to int.

Comment: @PietroNadalini `int.Parse` expects a string!

Comment: `int.Parse(Math.Round(1 / i * i))` ?

Comment: Thanks, I made a mistake, but I fixed it in case OP wanted to change the operation and it could return a decimal

Comment: call will be ambiguous between Math.Round(decimal) and Math.Round(double)

Comment: Since both 1 and i are ints, your Convert.ToInt32(Math.Round(1 / i * i)) will be 1 when i is 1 and 0 otherwise.

Comment: @AnkushMadankar, How could `(1 / i * i)` return Something else than an `int`. Int arithmetique is clear, 
Both [interger quotient](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/division-operator) and [mutiplication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/multiplication-operator) returns int. `object o = 1/5*5;Console.WriteLine(o.GetType());` will print "_System.Int32_"

Answer (score 0):

```
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int noofelement;
            do
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Could you please provide the total numbers of elements of this array?");
            } while (!int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(),out noofelement));


            int[] A = new int[noofelement] ;

            for (int i = 1; i <= noofelement; i++)
            {
                A[i-1] = (1 / i * i);
                Console.WriteLine(A[i-1]);
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
```

in this your code you can get 0 every time in **aaray**  in this **1 / i * i** operation.